# PostgreSQL OFFSET field consistency across processes

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to copy a Postgres table1 to another table2 while changing the value of one of the columns. To make the transfer faster I run 10 different processes each having different offsets in the table1 to start from, e.g., `1st process`: `SELECT * FROM table OFFSET offset1 LIMIT x;` then copy to `table2`, `2nd process`: `SELECT * FROM table OFFSET offset2 LIMIT x` then copy to `table2`.

But even though I don't have duplicate rows in my `table1` I do get duplicate rows in my `table2` (`x` is smaller than `offset2-offset1`). Is it possible that the same `offset` value  is not pointing to the same row in the table across different processes? If yes, what would be better way to copy a table while modifying a column in Postgres? Thanks!

Comment: Near duplicate: [PostgreSQL - repeating rows from LIMIT OFFSET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580826). The asker of that other question uses `order by`, but on a non-unique expression. BTW this is missing in Denis answer. Just using `ORDER BY` is not sufficient, it needs to be applied to a field or combination of fields or an expression that is unique across all rows.

Comment: Also, you should time `CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT...`, it's probably faster than the 10 different processes if these sessions are playing against each other to gain access to the disks, unless your postgres data partition is spread over a large number of physical drives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an `order by` statement, limit and offset are seldom meaningful... SQL offers no guarantee on row order unless you make it explicit. So add an `order by` clause.

Also, if copying a table wholesale is what you want, it's better to simply:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1
```