# Multi column order by kills postgresql performance, any way to fix?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a really simple query I'm running on a large table (500k rows) to page results.

Originally I was using this query, which is really fast:

```
 select * from deck 
    order by
        deck.sas_rating desc    
    limit 10
```

Its explain analyze show a 0.2ms execution time. Cool.

But the `sas_rating` column has duplicate integer values, and I realized when paging through the results (using offset for other pages) that I was getting duplicate results. No problem, add the primary key as a secondary order by. But the performance is *terrible*.

```
 select * from deck 
    order by
        deck.sas_rating desc,
        deck.id asc     
    limit 10
```

That takes 685ms with an explain analyze of:

```
Limit  (cost=164593.15..164593.17 rows=10 width=1496) (actual time=685.138..685.139 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=164593.15..165866.51 rows=509343 width=1496) (actual time=685.137..685.137 rows=10 loops=1)
        Sort Key: sas_rating DESC, id
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 59kB
        ->  Seq Scan on deck  (cost=0.00..153586.43 rows=509343 width=1496) (actual time=0.009..593.444 rows=509355 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.143 ms
Execution time: 685.171 ms
```

It's even worse on my weaker production server. My search went from 125ms total to 35 seconds!

I tried adding a multi-column index, but that didn't improve performance. Is there any way to prevent duplicate results when using limit + offset without destroying the performance of the query?

Comment: If you just want to get rid of duplicates on this column, it seems there is a `distinct on` in postgres: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24328 (near the end).

Comment: @dyukha There aren't duplicate rows. It's that when I select with `limit 10`, and then do another select with `limit 10 offset 10` I can retrieve some of the same results because `sas_rating` contains non-unique values. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13580826/1313268) for the problem, but no solution that works for me.

Comment: I see. What if you try to order by `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)`? Maybe something like here: https://zaiste.net/row_number_in_postgresql/ , but with `order by` instead of `where`. Sorry, I'm not sure it even works and have nowhere to test it.

Comment: Another option for pagination is described here: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you probably added your multi-column index wrong - for example you used `sas_rating, id` instead of `sas_rating desc, id`, as only the latter can be used for your order by.

The index on `sas_rating` only was usable for `sas_rating desc` sorting, as the database could go backwards over it. It is not the case for multi-column index - you have to preserve the ascending/descending order of columns as in the sort.

Comment: You're right. I just needed my multi-column index to use the proper `desc` order for `sas_rating`. I didn't even realize indexes had `desc` vs `asc`!

Comment: @Tometzky . . . Wow!  Great observation.  I think Postgres should be smart enough to use `(sas_rating, id)` for this purpose.  But that would require implementing skip scans.